# Changing the order of components doesn't yield desired result

Tags: css, asp.net, .net, layout

I have been trying to get the "Contact Us" part of this aspx to show up after the "Custom dial" part, but for some reason no matter what I try the custom dial is appearing after, not before. Does anyone know what I need to do to get the contact us link to move to the right side of the custom dial? This is driving me crazy.

```
<div style="clear: both;">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlLogo" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="logo_holder">
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="LogoLink">
            <asp:Image ID="imgLogoAdm" CssClass="logo" ImageUrl="~/Images/CompanyLogo.png" runat="server" />
        </asp:HyperLink>
        <span class="slogan"><strong>This is <br />
            Our Motto</strong></span>
        <span>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Width="25px">  </asp:Label>
            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="CustomDialHyperlink">
                <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgCustomDial" Width="160px" Height="80px" Visible="false" />
            </asp:HyperLink>
        </span>

        <span class="contact_info">
            <asp:HyperLink ID="ContactUs" NavigateUrl="~/ContactUs.aspx" runat="server"><strong>Contact Us</strong></asp:HyperLink>
        </span>

    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: It will depend on the CSS, so you will need to show the CSS for every class that is used here.

Comment: I did not know the css could control this.. that is likely my answer. Thank you